# Функция с изменяемым аргументом по умолчанию

Tags: python, функции

Есть вот такой код:

```py
def f(val, list=[]):
    list.append(val)
    return list

list1 = f(10)
list2 = f(123,[])
list3 = f('a')

print("list1 = %s" % list1)
print("list2 = %s" % list2)
print("list3 = %s" % list3)

# Вывод
# list1 = [10, 'a']
# list2 = [123]
# list3 = [10, 'a']
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вывод получился именно таким, как это работает?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, откуда взят этот код?

Comment: @V-Mor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159256/can-someone-explain-this-really-basic-python-code-to-me

Изучая питон, наткнулся вот на это, но английский не очень, мало чего оттуда понял и решил спросить у русских

Answer (score 1):

Функции в питоне вычисляются заранее. В следствие чего у вас создается ссылка на список list до выполнения скрипта, и поэтому все append пишутся в уже существующий список. Сама ваша функция во время выполнения скрипта список list заново не инициализирует. Поэтому хорошим тоном будет определять аргументы по умолчанию так:

```
def f(val, list=None):
    if not list: # или if list == None: 
        list=[]
    list.append(val)
    return list

somelist=[]

list1 = f(10)
list2 = f(123,[])
list3 = f('a')
list4 = f('b', somelist)
print("list4 = %s" % list4) # до обработки list5
list5 = f('c', list4)

print("list1 = %s" % list1)
print("list2 = %s" % list2)
print("list3 = %s" % list3)
print("list4 = %s" % list4) # после обработки list5
print("list5 = %s" % list5)
```

получим:

```
list4 = ['b']
list1 = [10]
list2 = [123]
list3 = ['a']
list4 = ['b', 'c']
list5 = ['b', 'c']
```